# PostgreSQL materialized view with global and partitioned ranks

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, window-functions, materialized-views

I have a table with 10 mils. of user ratings.
I need to create materialized view that has global rating and rating by country and is refreshed once a day.

I came up with the following select query:

```
SELECT row_number() OVER(ORDER BY value DESC, id) AS rank_global, 
       row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY country ORDER BY value DESC, id) AS rank_country,
       * 
FROM rate 
ORDER BY value DESC, id
LIMIT 100000
```

Is there a way to speed up this query or maybe there is another way to do the same? I created btree (value desc, id) and (country, value desc, id) indexes but it still takes a lot of time to complete.

Example:

Creating a table and populating it with users with random value column and random country:

```
CREATE TABLE rate
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  name text,
  value integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  country character varying,
  CONSTRAINT rate_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO rate 
(SELECT n, ('user_'||n), (random()*30)::int, ('country_'||(random()*3)::int) 
FROM generate_series(0,10) AS n);

CREATE INDEX rate_country_value_id_index
ON rate
USING btree(country, value DESC, id);

CREATE INDEX rate_value_id_index
ON rate
USING btree(value DESC, id);
```

Table contents:

```
id  name  value  country
0  user_0   28  country_2
1  user_1   24  country_2
2  user_2   29  country_1
3  user_3   11  country_1
4  user_4   16  country_1
5  user_5   28  country_0
6  user_6   3   country_1
7  user_7   7   country_1
8  user_8   28  country_1
9  user_9   4   country_0
10 user_10  29  country_1
```

Then I create materialized view:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW rate_view AS 
SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY value DESC, id) AS rgl, 
       row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY country ORDER BY value DESC, id) AS rc,
       * 
FROM rate 
ORDER BY value DESC, id;
```

View contents (rgl - global rank, rc - rank by country):

```
rgl rc id   name  value  country
1   1  2   user_2   29  country_1
2   2  10  user_10  29  country_1
3   1  5   user_5   28  country_0
4   1  0   user_0   28  country_2
5   3  8   user_8   28  country_1
6   2  1   user_1   24  country_2
7   4  4   user_4   16  country_1
8   5  3   user_3   11  country_1
9   6  7   user_7   7   country_1
10  2  9   user_9   4   country_0
11  7  6   user_6   3   country_1
```

Now i can create complex queries to select users with closest rank and its neighbours by rank. Both globally and by country.

For example, (after creating (value,id) and (rgl) indexes on view) here is global top 50 and 5 users closest by rank to value 9999942:

```
(
  WITH closest_rank AS
  ( 
    SELECT rgl FROM rate_view 
    WHERE value <= 9999942 
    ORDER BY value DESC, id ASC 
    LIMIT 1 
  )
  SELECT rgl, name, value 
  FROM rate_view 
  WHERE rgl > (SELECT rgl-3 FROM closest_rank ) 
  ORDER BY rgl ASC 
  LIMIT 5
)
UNION
SELECT rgl, name, value 
FROM rate_view 
WHERE rgl <=50 
ORDER BY rgl;
```

Comment: Could you please post the table definition? With a small example of data and expected result?

Comment: Description updated.